# Java Mosby Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mvp, mosby

How can I access MvpFragment from MvpActivity.

Fragment, with current code -

```
class Fragment1: MvpFragment<IView, Presenter>(){
    override fun createPresenter(): Presenter {
        return Presenter(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false)
    }
}
```

Activity is-

```
class MainActivity : MvpActivity<IView, Presenter>(), IView {
    override fun createPresenter(): Presenter {
        return Presenter(getApplicationContext())
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun create_fragment(view: View){
        var frgmnt = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        frgmnt.replace(R.id.containerZ, Fragment1())
    }
}
```

Comment: `i have trouble` We all do, but what's the issue you're having exactly?

Comment: frgmnt.replace(R.id.containerZ, Fragment1()) - that code is not working, because second param Fragment1()  is not a Fragment type. How can i rewrite this code?

Comment: Try doing an [edit]

Answer (score 0):

i think mosby uses support fragments so try this

```
var frgmnt = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
```